# scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b 'float' object not callable

Tags: python, fortran

I am experiencing 'float' object is not callable  error when I use `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` function.

As a variables of the function, I put

```
vec_final = op.fmin_l_bfgs_b(m.mod(b,n)[0],vec,m.mod(b,n)[1]).
```

`m.mod` is a subroutine mod of module `m`, which has output P and gradient of P. I used f2py to call this fortran subroutine to python.

```
(P = float, P gradient = array)
```

May I know what could be the problem? Thank you!!

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all questions related to Fortran. There is nothing at all Fortran 90 specific in your question (and actually not much Fortran at all). You say you used f2py to call "this fortran subroutine to python". Which *this subroutine*? What does the line `(P = float, P gradient = array)` mean? It does not look like Python or Fortran. Please show a [mcve].